# Google Places Error

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to perform a search using the Google Places API in my app but I'm getting an error.

my code:

```
public class GooglePlaces {

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();


    private static final String API_KEY = ""; 

    // Google Places serach url's
    private static final String PLACES_SEARCH_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
    private static final String PLACES_DETAILS_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?";

    private double _latitude;
    private double _longitude;
    private double _radius;

    /**
     * Searching places
     * @param latitude - latitude of place
     * @params longitude - longitude of place
     * @param radius - radius of searchable area
     * @param types - type of place to search
     * @return list of places
     * */
    public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
            throws Exception {

        this._latitude = latitude;
        this._longitude = longitude;
        this._radius = radius;



        try {
            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request ;
            request  = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_SEARCH_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("location", _latitude + "," + _longitude);
            request.getUrl().put("radius", _radius); // in meters
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");
            if(types != null)
                request.getUrl().put("types", types);

            PlacesList list = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);
            // Check log cat for places response status
            Log.d("Places Status", "" + list.status);
            return list;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error:", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Searching single place full details
     * @paramrefrence - reference id of place
     *                 - which you will get in search api request
     * */
    public PlaceDetails getPlaceDetails(String reference) throws Exception {
        try {

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(PLACES_DETAILS_URL));
            request.getUrl().put("key", API_KEY);
            request.getUrl().put("reference", reference);
            request.getUrl().put("sensor", "false");

            PlaceDetails place = request.execute().parseAs(PlaceDetails.class);

            return place;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error in Perform Detail", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating http request Factory
     * */
    public static HttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(
            final HttpTransport transport) {
        return transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("com-xink-vn");
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                JsonHttpParser parser = new JsonHttpParser(new JacksonFactory());
                request.addParser(parser);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Error log:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions
        at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:164)
        at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.of(ClassInfo.java:92)
        at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:79)
        at com.google.api.client.util.GenericData.<init>(GenericData.java:61)
        at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:97)
        at com.vog.utils.GooglePlaces.search(GooglePlaces.java:59)
        at com.vog.xink.EditPictureActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(EditPictureActivity.java:606)
        at com.vog.xink.EditPictureActivity$LoadPlaces.doInBackground(EditPictureActivity.java:576)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: You need to add [com.google.common.base.Preconditions](http://www.findjar.com/class/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) to your JAR.

Comment: I added google-collections-0.8 into my project but i get a new error:  
         
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.<init>(FieldInfo.java:131)
            at com.google.api.client.util.FieldInfo.of(FieldInfo.java:104)
            at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.<init>(ClassInfo.java:181)
            at com.google.api.client.util.ClassInfo.of(ClassInfo.java:92)

Comment: would probably be more helpful if you post the entire new error log